# Line 6 of this Javascript program is confusing me

Tags: javascript

In the function `takeNormal()` below, there is a line that I don't understand at all. It is:

```
var end = reduce(Math.min, text.length, map(indexOrEnd, ["*", "{"]));
```

Specifically, in this function reduce, it has all these different arguments (are they arguments?). How are they processed by reduce? Are they handled one after the other? Or, for example, does `Math.min` do anything to `text.length`? How do the different parts in reduce interact and what does reduce ultimately do to them?

```
  function splitParagraph(text) {
  function indexOrEnd(character) {
    var index = text.indexOf(character);
    return index == -1 ? text.length : index;
  }

  function takeNormal() {
    var end = reduce(Math.min, text.length,
                     map(indexOrEnd, ["*", "{"]));
    var part = text.slice(0, end);
    text = text.slice(end);
    return part;
  }

  function takeUpTo(character) {
    var end = text.indexOf(character, 1);
    if (end == -1)
      throw new Error("Missing closing '" + character + "'");
    var part = text.slice(1, end);
    text = text.slice(end + 1);
    return part;
  }

  var fragments = [];

  while (text != "") {
    if (text.charAt(0) == "*")
      fragments.push({type: "emphasised",
                      content: takeUpTo("*")});
    else if (text.charAt(0) == "{")
      fragments.push({type: "footnote",
                      content: takeUpTo("}")});
    else
      fragments.push({type: "normal",
                      content: takeNormal()});
  }
  return fragments;
}
```

Comment: where are these `reduce` and `map` functions defined?

Comment: This code makes me jealous. I wish the JavaScript 1.8 extensions were available for cross-browser use.

Comment: I have no idea. This is a tutorial from a javascript book. Not a complete program.

Comment: @John http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: So in the code in the OP, Math.map would be the callback function that gets applied to the array, but what is the initialValue?IN the code in the OP, there is also text.length and the map function. How do those work within the context explained by Mozilla ?array.reduce(callback[, initialValue])

Parameters

callback
Function to execute on each value in the array.
initialValue
Object to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback.